# Limiting UITextView to one line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

Is there a way to limit UITextView to one line, whereby I can fill it with any amount of text and it will resize horizontally to match: like so:

```
-----------
| cheese  |
-----------
```

... when filled with longer text becomes

```
--------------------------
| the last man on earth  |
--------------------------
```

(the lines indicate the edges of the UITextView)

Comment: `UITextField` has always been a single line anyway.

Comment: Did you mean `textView` ? `textField` resize horizontally by default.

Comment: sorry i meant text view... now changed.

Comment: ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved by inheriting UITextView class as

```
@interface InputTextView : UITextView
@end

@implementation InputTextView

/*************************************************
* fixes the issue with single lined uitextview
*************************************************/
- (UIEdgeInsets) contentInset { return UIEdgeInsetsZero; }

@end
```

for further reference go-through [here](http://doli.at/2010/05/09/single-line-uitextview/)